# How to calculate average with a void method and repeated method calls?

Tags: java

I have a void method that takes a single integer so that it can update a value stored in a class object to an average. The conceit here is that every time I call this method, it must update the sum stored in the method and then re-average it. The problem is that the first two JUnit tests I have that run checks for one and two calls work fine, but the third one miscalculates. I'm sure this is because it is simply taking the third value and adding it to the previous average rather than sum, but I'm not sure how to reconcile this and am completely stumped. Is there a more proper way to do this rather than passing the parameter into an ArrayList? I'm probably missing something obvious since I am pretty new.

```
public void getAverage(int value) {
    ArrayList<Integer> valueList = new valueList<Integer>();
    valueList.add(value);
    int sum = this.mean; //instance variable that must hold average
    for (int val : valueList) {
        sum += val;
        this.mean = sum;
        this.numValues++; //instance variable for how many entries
    }
    sum = this.mean / this.numValues;
    this.mean = sum;


}
```

Comment: After a quick look you might just be setting `this.mean` as itself divided by `this.numValues`. Also your creating a new `ArrayList` on each method call, maybe localize this?

Comment: Yeah, it was a quite a mess. Possible false positives from not filling the array probably weren't helping. Made the valueList an instance variable and fixed the redundancy in and after the for each. Also removed numValues and am just dividing the sum by valueList.size() because it seems more concise. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `valueList` is a local variable and is newly created on every method call, hence it will only hold 1 value and which is your `value` and not all the previous method call values.

To fix, move your `valueList` to the class as an instance variable.

Comment: Ah. Brilliant. I can't believe I missed that even after my test with System.out.println(valueList.size()) was printing repeating 1's. Guess you just need some other eyes sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a new `ArrayList` every method call. put in inside the class so it doesn't get deleted when the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Once you move your list to where it should be, you can get the average as a double any time you add a new value to it by using streams in Java 8:

```
mean = valueList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).summaryStatistics().getAverage();
```